# How do I change the button mapping of jumping in unity to the X instead of Square on my PlayStation controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

so when using the unity GetButtonDown("Jump") it automatically keeps space bar as the jump button, however, when using unity with a controller the button is mapped to square instead of x if there is anyway to change this please let me know!

I tried doing an action map and maybe relaying it there but to be honest I'm really new to Unity and coding in general so following youtube tutorials did end up getting me more confused.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are 2 input systems in unity and it sounds like this is where the confusion is coming from.  `Input` api is the old input system, which can be managed through the Input Manager `Edit>Project Settings>Input Manager`.  The `Input System` package uses action maps and can be managed through the `Action Editor` or by code (once you have imported the package).

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Action Mapping, but if you're using the standard Input Manager, then go to Project Settings -> Input Manager -> Axes, find the second entry for "Jump" (the first one is for keyboard), and change its default (for me, I see "joystick button 3") to the button you want it to be.

Here's the docs for the Input Manager, for future reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html